# Running pgadmin throw an unexpected error

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I have installed postgresql and pgadmin in my ubuntu 20.04 machine.

but I face this error when I running this command in the terminal: `python pgAdmin4.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pgAdmin4.py", line 92, in <module>
app = create_app()
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 350, in create_app
db_upgrade(app)
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/db_upgrade.py", line 25, in db_upgrade
flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 95, in wrapped
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 280, in upgrade
command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", 
line 298, in upgrade
script.run_env()
 File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", 
line 489, in run_env
util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
   File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/../../migrations/env.py", line 94, in <module>
      run_migrations_online()
   File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/../../migrations/env.py", line 87, in run_migrations_online
     context.run_migrations()
    File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
   File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
   File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 520, in run_migrations
     step.migration_fn(**kw)
    File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/migrations/versions/3c1e4b6eda55_.py", line 20, in upgrade
     db.engine.execute(
    File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2238, in execute
      return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
    File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1006, in execute
     return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
    File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1175, in _execute_text
    ret = self._execute_context(
    File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
     File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
      util.raise_(
      File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
      raise exception
      File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
      self.dialect.do_execute(
     File "/home/farhad/Public/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: hostaddr
   [SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN hostaddr TEXT(1024)]
   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

before that I have installed it frequently, without any problem.

I have installed postgresql with this command:

`sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

Then I installed pgadmin based on below steps:

1. running command `sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libgmp3-dev virtualenv python3-pip libpq-dev python-dev`
2. create a directory named `pgadmin` in somewhere in my system.
3. using `virtualenv` to create an isolated environment and running command `virtualenv pgadmin`.
4. `cd pgadmin`.
5. `source bin/activate`
6. run command `wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.23/pip/pgadmin4-4.23-py3-none-any.whl`.
7. Installing it using python pip: `pip install  pgadmin4-4.23-py3-none-any.whl`
8. creating a file named `config_local.py` in this path:

`/pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4`

and put this content to it:

```
import os
DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgAdmin/'))
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgAdmin4.log')
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgAdmin4.db')
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions')
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = False
```

9. And finally when I run pgadmin by command `python /pgadmin/pgadmin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin4.py` face to that error.

Comment: It says `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: hostaddr  [SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN hostaddr TEXT(1024)]
   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)` Did you check the link out?

Comment: Where should I look for for server table? in postgresql none of databases has server table.

Comment: It is a Sqlite3 table , presumably the data store pgAdmin is using in the browser to maintain metadata. Remember pgAdmin != Postgres, it is just a client program. Best guess is 'SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgAdmin4.db')' is pointing at existing Sqlite3 database and the new install is trying to modify it and failing for the reason in the error. Move that db out of the way and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to sqlite database of pgadmin.

The sqlite database was located in `~/.pgAdmin/pgAdmin4.db`. I removed `~/.pgAdmin` directory and reinstall pgadmin. It was corrected.